# IntegrityError at /new_entry/3/ NOT NULL constraint failed: learning_logs_entry.user_id

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/84zxH.png(Please see the picture)

My new_entry() function was working fine lately but now it is not saving the form and shows error at new_entry.save().
I don't understand why the error is happening.

My function

```
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    """Add a new entry for a particular topic"""
    topic= Topic.objects.get(id=topic_id)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        #No data submitted: create a blank form.
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        # POST data submitted ; create a blank form.
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_entry= form.save(commit=False)
            new_entry.topic = topic
            new_entry.owner=request.user
            new_entry.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('learning_logs:topic',
                                                args=[topic_id]))

    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html',context)
```

My models.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic user is learning about"""
    text=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    
    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.text
class Entry(models.Model):
    """Something specific learned about the topic"""
    topic=models.ForeignKey('Topic',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text=models.TextField()
    date_added=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural='entries'

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of model"""
        return self.text[:50] +"..."
```

my template

```
{% extends 'learning_logs/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

  <p>Topic: {{ topic }}</p>
  
  <p>Entries:</p>
  <p>
    <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:new_entry' topic.id %}">add new entry</a>
  </p>
  <ul>
  {% for entry in entries %}
    <li>
      <b><p>{{ entry.date_added|date:'M d, Y H:i' }}</p></b>
      <p>{{ entry.text|linebreaks }}</p>
       @{{current_user.username}}
       <a href="{% url 'learning_logs:edit_entry' entry.id %}">edit entry</a>
      </p>
    </li>
  {% empty %}
    <li>
      There are no entries for this topic yet.
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
  </ul>
  

{% endblock content %}
```

THANK YOU

Comment: Maybe its happening because i have started working with bootstrap in base.html but still have not loaded bootstrap in new_entry.html and not modified the code.

Answer (score 0):

`Entry` has no <s>`owner = …`</s> field, but a `user = …` field, so you should set the logged in user to the `.user` of the `Entry` object:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect

@login_required
def new_entry(request, topic_id):
    topic = get_object_or_404(Topic, id=topic_id)
    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = EntryForm()
    else:
        form = EntryForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.topic = topic
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('learning_logs:topic', topic_id)
    context = {'topic': topic, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'learning_logs/new_entry.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Can you please tell me why the form requires a user instance .Please

Comment: @ShresthSingh: the form does not, the instance wrapped in the form, since you save it to the database, and it is a non-nullable field, this means that the database will reject it.